# How to use useNavigation()

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a dummy screen which I want to navigate from any page of the application.

Parent component:

```
import DummyComponent  from "./DummyComponent";
const navigation = useNavigation();

const dummyPage = () => {
    navigation.navigate(DummyComponent);    
  }

<TouchableOpacity onPress={dummyPage}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", width: 150, height: 50}}>
        <Text>Dummy</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But when I press Dummy text, then nothing happens. I am very new to using hooks, and particularly I am having difficulty in useNavigation(). Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: hooks should be used in components. You add it under imports?

Answer (score 0):

How did you define the routes?

Try `navigation.navigate('DummyComponent');`

Answer (score 0):

For that you must have to create a stack container for your screens between which you want to navigate here is link to  [Create Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator) for moving between screen check this link [Moving between screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating) they are extracting navigation from props but if don't fellow their way then you can use **useNavigation()** instead of **prop.navigation.navigte('ScreenName')'**